# Problems with touch detection

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone, touch

I'm just learning Cocos2d and Objective-C, and I have some problems with touch detection.

I have several sprites in `HelloWorldLayer` and some draggableSprites (NSMutableArray). Two of the draggableSprites are located one over another (the bottom one is bigger).

Then i have some code that shakes a touched sprite:

```
- (void)selectSpriteForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
    CCSprite *touchSprite = nil;
    for (CCSprite *sprite in dragableSprites) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation)) {            
            touchSprite = sprite;
            break;
        }
    }    
    if (touchSprite != selSprite) {
        [selSprite stopAllActions];
        [selSprite runAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:0]];
        CCRotateTo * rotLeft = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:-1.0];
        CCRotateTo * rotCenter = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:0.0];
        CCRotateTo * rotRight = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:1.0];
        CCSequence * rotSeq = [CCSequence actions:rotLeft, rotCenter, rotRight, rotCenter, nil];
        [touchSprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:rotSeq]];            
        selSprite = touchSprite;
    }
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    [self selectSpriteForTouch:touchLocation];   
    return TRUE;
}
```

But when I touch the top or bottom sprites, only bottom one is shaking (it was added first in init).

I think that I need to replace the code `CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation)`, but I just don't know how.

I spent several nights on forums but I still can't understand how to make the top sprite shake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this (notice it is `ccTouchesBegan` not `ccTouchBegan`):

```
- (void)startShakingSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite {

    [sprite stopAllActions];
    [sprite runAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:0]];
    CCRotateTo* rotLeft = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:-1.0];
    CCRotateTo* rotCenter = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:0.0];
    CCRotateTo* rotRight = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:1.0];
    CCSequence* rotSeq = [CCSequence actions:rotLeft, rotCenter, rotRight, rotCenter, nil];
    [sprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:rotSeq]];  
}

- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    //get the touch
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    //get its location
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    //convert location to cocos2d coordinates
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(location.x, 480 - location.y);

    //now we go through your array of objects and see which contains the touch
    for(id sprite in draggableSprites) {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, point)) {
            [self startShakingSprite:sprite];
        }
    }
}
```

The way the for loop is set up in `selectSpriteForTouch` will cause only the first object in `draggableSprites` to be selected, because of your `break` statement. With this new code, each sprite whose bounding box contains the touch will be animated. The code might not be perfect because I typed it straight into Chrome, but you get the idea.

Another important thing to note is that you cannot run the same action on two different sprites, like this:

```
id action = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:1.0];
[someSprite runAction:action];
[someOtherSprite runAction:action];
[oneMoreSprite runAction:action];
```

This code will not work as intended; only the last sprite(`oneMoreSprite`) will be animated. In order to re-use CC animations with multiple sprites, use this code:

```
id action = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:1.0];
[someSprite runAction:action];
[someOtherSprite runAction:[[action copy] autorelease]];
[oneMoreSprite runAction:[[action copy] autorelease]];
```

We make a copy of the action so it can be run by another sprite (`someOtherSprite`, `oneMoreSprite`) without removing it from the original sprite, `someSprite`. Then, we autorelease it so we don't have a memory leak.